# unordered map in C++ // load factor // variance of entries per bucket

Tags: c++11, hash, unordered-map

I have a question regarding key/bucket statistics for a hash table. The load factor value (occupied entries in the hash table / the number of buckets) does not seem to be very beneficial. Keeping the load factor below some bound guarantees an appropriate load of the hash table, but does not take potential collisions into account. Having a very low load factor, it might happen that one bucket contains over 70% of the whole data (e.g. due to bad hashing).

Am I right that you should take care of both the load factor and variance of number of entries per bucket by yourself? Does C++11 provide any advanced tools for checking both at the same time? How shall one decide what is a good combination of the load and variance?

Thanks!

Best,
Alexey

Comment: There's [`unordered_map::bucket_size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/bucket_size) if that's what you are looking for. I'm not sure how this is useful though. Suppose you discover that the hash function is so bad that everything does in fact end up in one bucket - now what? What can you do about it, short of designing a better hash function?

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly my concern. You can manually check your bucket sizes, but it is somehow unclear to me what a desired bucket size is... a few collisions will certainly not hurt the performance.

Comment: What's the point of devising a metric, if you can do nothing to improve it anyway? When you say you intend to "take care" of variance, what exactly did you mean by that? What possible courses of action do you believe to have at your disposal?

Comment: I am agree with your arguments, sure, I would just wish a more advanced metric for measuring load / variance of hash tables.